# Can Anybody tell me, Simply use of Bit wise Operator in SQL Query with example

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not sure about when, and how bit-wise operator are working with our query like SP, or function.

Can anybody tell me with simple example to understand about bit-wise operator.

Comment: ANSI SQL has no such operator. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I m using SQL server 2012

Comment: You should probably avoid bit-wise operators.

Comment: In this link shows how operator behaves, but i want to know about how this use in my query.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-operators-transact-sql

Comment: What does your query look like?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question you would like to know what bitwise operatrions are used for and how to do it.

without going into detail bitwise operators work on bitmaps, bitmaps are a way to use one number to store multiple properties.

say we want one number to store personal info about a persons e.g. gender and marital status.

we start by assigning the properties we want to track binary whole numbers i.e.

```
Male = 2
Female = 4
Trans = 8
Single = 16
married = 32
Divorced = 64
```

so a married male would be represented by 34 Male(2) + Married(32) = 34

it is easy to test for properties with bitwise operators like this

```
DECLARE @Male AS INT
DECLARE @FeMale AS INT
DECLARE @Trans AS INT
DECLARE @Single AS INT
DECLARE @Married AS INT
DECLARE @Divorced AS INT

SET @Male = 2
SET @Female = 4
SET @Trans = 8
SET @Single = 16
SET @Married = 32
SET @Divorced = 64

DECLARE @Person AS INT

-- Married male is 34
SET @Person = @male + @Married

-- Is person female?
IF @person & @female = @female
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'They are female'
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'Not Female'
  END
```

Comment: And you could select for instance all maried or previous maried with something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE state & (@married + @divorced)` . As far as I understand SQL will not use an index for this type of query tthough so this results in a full-table scan. Acceptable for small(er) tables

Answer (score 0):

in TSQL it would be something like

```
SELECT a_int_value & b_int_value  
FROM bitwise;
```

according to [& (Bitwise AND) (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql)